# installed azure PHP sdk via web platform manager but can't use the api

Tags: php, azure, sdk

I have installed the azure PHP SDK via IIS web platform manager. But I am unable to use the API.

After calling the API like this:

```
<?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php"; 

echo 'Azure test';

?>
```

I get the following error:

HP Warning:  require_once(vendor/autoload.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\azure.php on line 3
PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\azure.php on line 3

I am not sure why it is looking for a pear package.

Any idea why it is not working.

Thanks

Comment: vendor/autoload.php

Is not located where you are trying to require it. Where is the script that runs the require and where is the autoload.php?

Comment: Looks like your need to install the vendor/autoload.php to enable the autoloader. I think [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) will help your.

Comment: It seems to have worked, I see an autoload file in vendor, should I include this in my "include_path" file in my php.ini, so it is automatically called from whatever directory. Or do I need to stick all my related php files in the same directory as these

Comment: @hfcorriez - you should move your comment to an Answer, since that appeared to actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As hfcorriez said yes.
I thinks you just need add pear packages to your "include_path", your auto_load class will call them.